# Can I use Switch Widget with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My application uses actionbarsherlock. My question is can I use Switch Widget, along with actionbarsherlock (switch widget appearing as part of actionbarsherlock)? Is it supported?

I have read questions regarding actionbarsherlock and switch widget, but none of them really answered my question.

If the answer is Yes, can someone point me to an example?

Comment: There is a `Switch` backport available, though it is separate from ActionBarSherlock: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/switch-compat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. The switch widget is not part of the ActionBar and therefore not part of ActionBarSherlock.

You can only use it if you target API Level 14 or up or if you recreate it from the Android source code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setCustomView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) method to insert whatever layout you want in the Android ActionBar and therefor also with `ActionBarSherlock` that has exactly the same API.

So you can just add a layout with a [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) in it.

To use it in API < 14 I've personally gone through the process of importing the [Switch open-source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/Switch.java) into my project and it's not that paintfull.